# WordPress Categories Unique to a Page

Tags: wordpress

How do I get a wordpress post with the category "dog" to go on one page (note: not the title of the post but only the content of it), and another post with the category "lion" to go on a separate page (note: title and an excerpt)? How would I code this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has the default functionality. 
Use the category widget of sidebar to get the URL.
Add the menu item from menu section and give there full path of the category.